# Android Vector Asset Studio gives extra padding to some vector images

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to import some icons from Material Vector package in Vector Asset Studio.

But they come with padding.

[image]

Why does this happen and how can I remove it?

This is inconvenient because this means if I want my icon to be 17dp x 17dp in XML, then I need to set it more than 17x17 to make up for the padding.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can adjust for any "implicit" padding that may be contained within a `VectorDrawables` source image (`.SVG`, `.PSD`) by setting your `ImageViews` `android:scaleType` to the appropriate value so it can handle the padding that is secretly contained in the `VectorDrawables` source image. You will also need to set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`.

For example, lets say your `VectorDrawable` has some really annoying `padding` at the start of the image when you display it. You have no idea why it's there because you aren't setting any `android:paddingStart` on the `ImageView`... what you need to do is set the `ImageViews` `android:scaleType` to `fitStart` and `android:adjustViewBounds` to `true`.

**tl;dr**

Adjust your `ImageViews` `android:scaleType` to handle any "implicit" padding that is contained in your `VectorDrawable`s source file (`.SVG`, `.PSD`). Also set `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`.

**Quick Example:**

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/vectorDrawable_imageView"
           <!--Other ImageView settings-->
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
           android:scaleType="fitStart"
           app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_with_implicit_padding_at_start"
/>
```

This will remove that annoying "implicit" padding that was at the start of your `VectorDrawable`.

**Note:** Adjust the `android:scaleType` according to your rendering needs.

Answer (score 65):

**Android Vector Asset**

You are able to scale a vector that will remove additional space. This is possible using `group` tag. Just modify your vector xml file.

From

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,4l-1.41,1.41L16.17,11H4v2h12.17l-5.58,5.59L12,20l8,-8z" />
</vector>
```

to

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">

    <group
        android:pivotX="12"
        android:pivotY="12"
        android:scaleX="1.5"
        android:scaleY="1.5">

        <path
            android:fillColor="#FF000000"
            android:pathData="M12,4l-1.41,1.41L16.17,11H4v2h12.17l-5.58,5.59L12,20l8,-8z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

As result

[image]

Comment: Great solution, I like it because it doesn't require you to change the ImageView, only the source drawable. Plus, it seems to work on Amazon devices too, which are quite picky on their vector drawables.

Comment: For me, this just let the image become bigger, the inner padding still exists.

Answer (score 5):

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="28"
    android:viewportHeight="28">
    <group
        android:translateX="2"
        android:translateY="2">
        <path
            android:fillColor="#8A333333"
            android:pathData="M13.12,2.06L7.58,7.6c-0.37,0.37 -0.58,0.88 -0.58,1.41V19c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h9c0.8,0 1.52,-0.48 1.84,-1.21l3.26,-7.61C23.94,10.2 22.49,8 20.34,8h-5.65l0.95,-4.58c0.1,-0.5 -0.05,-1.01 -0.41,-1.37 -0.59,-0.58 -1.53,-0.58 -2.11,0.01zM3,21c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2v-8c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2s-2,0.9 -2,2v8c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2z" />
    </group>
</vector>
```

android:viewportWidth  += android:translateX * 2 (padding start / end)

android:viewportHeight += android:translateY * 2 (padding top / bottom)

Answer (score 3):

This padding is on some icons so that all of the icons can align properly. For example, if in that dialog, you pick `ic_3d_rotation_24dp`, you'll see the icon goes all the way to the edge of the bounds.

PS if you aim to have [all your sizes be a multiple of 8dp](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-baseline-grids), things will line up nicely and look great.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that. I thought it was either a bug or a feature that can be disabled.