# How to fit VectorDrawable to ImageView and remove unnecessary paddings

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

For my Android app I've created such layer list from two vector Drawable.

[The xml-code](https://gist.github.com/LAHomieJob/1da162b07d3a820e4e9ae8b4d72db10a)

[image: Image Drawable]

I want to put this image into ImageView, but I have a problem with paddings which I can't remove (marked in red)[image].

To solve this issue I've already applied follow steps:

1. Explicitly set paddings to 0 value
2. Set "AdjustViewBound" to true
3. Played with "fitType" attributes.

None of this hadn't been worked for me. Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: remove paddings from buyer_item_circle_icon.xml  file inside item tag

Comment: I've tried it. No Result(

Comment: The problem is that your designer has left padding around the outside of the icon.  Either ask your designer to fix the icon, or go with @Giovanne's solution which sclaes the icon up to fit the VectorDrawable dimensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should get a whole drawable with the circle and person in one vector. But if you really need these two files to be separated, you must change the path in the XML code.

Accordingly to this 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50114171/3368784 you can resize your path by rewriting your `primary_dark_color_circle.xml`
as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <group
        android:pivotX="12"
        android:pivotY="12"
        android:scaleX="1.2"
        android:scaleY="1.2">
        <path
            android:fillColor="#0088CC"
            android:pathData="M12,12m-10,0a10,10 0,1 1,20 0a10,10 0,1 1,-20 0" />
    </group>
</vector>
```