# Delete padding or Force fitting or Delete empty space from square Vector asset to Fit a Rectangular button?

Tags: android, svg, imageview, padding, crop

I'm trying to adjust the [all_inclusive svg image](https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=all_inclusive) to my rectangular button. The shape itself is rectangular as well but the vector asset is square (24x24) with white spaces above and under the shape. These spaces force the shape itself to be very small. How to make the all inclusive svg rectangular by deleting that padding on top and on bottom?

[image: annoying_infinity]

In this picture the image is set to fit the guidelines on the left, top and right side:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgInfinity"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_infinity"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="0.75"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="0.75"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="0.25" />
```

Things that did not work:

- pivot vector asset [with a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652834/android-vector-asset-studio-gives-extra-padding-to-some-vector-images/50114171#50114171) -> I just cant figure out the dimensions without messing up the original shape. Same storty with scaleX/Y or translateX/Y. I got it to work on my other buttons with simpler shapes though.
- adjusting android:viewportheight or android:height -> it deshapes the picture to a weird form
- crop svg online --> as Googles original SVG pathData is already 580 characters long, cropping tools only make it to large for android to deal with (above 1000 charactes)
- crop svg picture with word and extract from zip file-> it doesnt compress svg images so it stays rectangular with the white spaces above and under.
- Set a seperate horizontal guideline for the top of the picture. It does the trick but one or multiple guidelines for each image gets very messy. There must be a better way, right?..

**ACCEPTED SOLUTION (edit with InkShape):**

- Install [InkShape](https://inkscape.org/)
- Open SVG
- Click on picture once to select it
- Go to File-> Document Properties and click 'Resize pager to drawing or selection' (this button is hidden on the first tab, click +Resize page to content to show the option);
- Save
- extract pathData and (viewport)width/heights from saved file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update using Inkscape version 1.1:**

Unfortunately, the latest version of Inkscape (1.1) no longer will import a vector drawable file directly, so the original answer is not 100% correct. That answer will probably work with other editors that can handle vector drawable files.

Here is an update to that answer that works with later versions of Inkscape to remove all padding from a vector drawable.

**Convert vector drawable to scaled vector graphic (SVG):**

- Open Alex Lockwood's [Shape Shifter site](https://shapeshifter.design/)
- Drag the vector drawable file from Android Studio to Shape Shifter.
- Export the image as an SVG to a local file

**Now that we have an SVG file, we can edit it with Inkscape:**

- Install Inkscape if not already installed.
- Open SVG file in Inkscape.
- Click on the image to select it.
- Resize the image to the selection (Shift+Ctrl+R or Edit->Resize Page to Selection). You can also specify an alternate size if you desire some padding.
- Save the image as an SVG file.

**The image is now cropped in an SVG file. We need to convert it back to a vector drawable.**

- In Android Studio import the SVG file as a vector drawable. (File->New->Vector Asset) Asset Type = "Local file (SVG, PSD).

Once imported, the vector drawable no longer has any padding.

Use an image editor that can handle SVG files to crop the image. I used InkScape but there are others. Once the image is cropped, you can import it into Android Studio as an XML file.

Comment: When I save the file with inkshape a lot of other properties are saved as well. Did you manually copy the pathdata and dimenstions to get "resulting cropped image file:"? Or is there a sort of 'save to android svg'-button somewhere that I missed?

Comment: @l3ob I grabbed the SVG file that you referenced, cropped it and saved it as an SVG file. I then imported that SVG file into Android Studio which made it into  vector drawable with an ".xml" suffix. Vector drawables implement a subset of the SVG spec, so a lot is stripped out during the import process. I didn't have to do any manual editing.

Answer (score 3):

The `viewportHeight` attribute defines the size of the "canvas" that the path is drawn on (i.e., it defines what the coordinates in the path data actually "mean").

The `height` attribute defines the intrinsic size of the drawable.

The original vector has 6.5 units (in the viewport) of white space at the top and the bottom. That means that you can look for any `pathData` command that uses a capital letter, and subtract 6.5 from the y coordinate. That leaves you with this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="13dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="13.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M18.6,0.12c-1.44,0 -2.8,0.56 -3.77,1.53L12,4.16 10.48,5.5h0.01L7.8,7.89c-0.64,0.64 -1.49,0.99 -2.4,0.99 -1.87,0 -3.39,-1.51 -3.39,-3.38S3.53,2.12 5.4,2.12c0.91,0 1.76,0.35 2.44,1.03l1.13,1 1.51,-1.34L9.22,1.7C8.2,0.68 6.84,0.12 5.4,0.12 2.42,0.12 0,2.54 0,5.5s2.42,5.38 5.4,5.38c1.44,0 2.8,-0.56 3.77,-1.53l2.83,-2.5 0.01,0.01L13.52,5.5h-0.01l2.69,-2.39c0.64,-0.64 1.49,-0.99 2.4,-0.99 1.87,0 3.39,1.51 3.39,3.38s-1.52,3.38 -3.39,3.38c-0.9,0 -1.76,-0.35 -2.44,-1.03l-1.14,-1.01 -1.51,1.34 1.27,1.12c1.02,1.01 2.37,1.57 3.82,1.57 2.98,0 5.4,-2.41 5.4,-5.38s-2.42,-5.37 -5.4,-5.37z"/>
</vector>
```

Then, once the whole shape has been moved "up" by 6.5 units, you can subtract 11 (6.5 * 2) from both the viewport and the intrinsic height.

The end result is a 24x13dp shape, which should scale much better in wide views.

Comment: Thank you, I needed this explanation to undestand how to manually adjust SVG files. However I accepted @Cheticamp answere as it is faster and more convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the new update on this topic:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202019

It looks like using android:scaleType="fitXY" will make it scale correctly on Lollipop.

From a Google engineer:

> Hi, Let me know if scaleType='fitXY' can be a workaround for you , in
>   order to get the image look sharp.
>
> The marshmallow Vs Lollipop is due to a special scaling treatment
>   added into marshmallow.
>
> Also, for your comments: " Correct behavior: The vector drawable
>   should scale without quality loss. So if we want to use the same asset
>   in 3 different sizes in our application, we don't have to duplicate
>   vector_drawable.xml 3 times with different hardcoded sizes. "
>
> Even though I totally agree this should be the case, in reality, the
>   Android platform has performance concern such that we have not reach
>   the ideal world yet. So it is actually recommended to use 3 different
>   vector_drawable.xml for better performance if you are sure you want to
>   draw 3 different size on the screen at the same time.
>
> The technical detail is basically we are using a bitmap under the hook
>   to cache the complex path rendering, such that we can get the best
>   redrawing performance, on a par with redrawing a bitmap drawable.

Comment: I tried the fitXY property on the group but it didnt seem to work and dont want to spend time reading why not. Thanks anyway