# Drawable with arrow indicator at top right corner?

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, shapes

can anyone please guide me
How i can make a drawable file to have a view like this image?

I have the border drawable here but not able to figure out on how can i draw arrow indicator over there

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <stroke
                android:width="@dimen/size_1"
                android:color="@color/white_four" />
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/layout_margin_3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border_drawbale_with_arrow_indicator"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView/>
        <Separator/>
        <TextView/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image: Text]

Comment: Take a look at using a [NinePatchDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/NinePatchDrawable).

Comment: @Cheticamp sorry didnt understand this, NinePatchDrawable converts image to extendable bitmap, the above is the snippet i took of the entire screen

Comment: It's just the white area with the little triangle cap, right? A nine-patch will work but it may not scale exactly as you would like. A better solution would be to use a vector drawable which will scale nicely. You would have to create it, though. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60212313/6287910) is one way to go about it. I don't see a way to do what you want just with an XML drawable file that would work in all circumstances.